# How do I html decode dropdownlist datatextfield?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a product name eg, "Ham `&amp;` Egg" and I to want show in the dropdownlist as "Ham & Egg" but I don't seem to be able to display it with this code here:

```
drpProd.DataSource = Productlib.Product_SelectAll();
drpProd.DataTextField = Server.HtmlDecode("ProdName");
drpProd.DataValueField = "ProdID";
drpProd.DataBind();
drpProd.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("------Select One Please------"));
```

Even after I used Server.HtmlDecode("ProdName"), it still displays as "Ham `&amp;` Egg". How should I go about it? Thanks a lot and in advance.

Comment: `Server.HtmlDecode("ProdName")` will not decode the value of ProdName property. You  should create a new property in Product class which will return encoded value of ProdName property. And set that property name as DataTextField of drop-down list.

Comment: Why are you storing the data encoded as HTML? the dropdown will take care of the encoding.

Comment: I am using HTML Encoding to prevent XSS in the input field.

Comment: So, the name comes from an input field in a form, right? If that's the case then you must decode the name before it's stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Chetan Ranpariya, thanks for giving me a hint and thanks guys I have managed to solve it and here is the code:

```
SqlDataReader dr = Productlib.Product_SelectAll()
while (dr.Read())
    {
       ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
       listItem.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(dr["ProdName"].ToString());
       listItem.Value = dr["ProdID"].ToString();
       drpProd.Items.Add(listItem);
     }
  drpProd.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("------Select One Please------"));
```